# How do I use the npm classnames library in next.js to optionally apply styles from a css file?

Tags: next.js, class-names

In the html below, I am optionally applying the bootstrap classes, alert-danger or alert-primary depending on message.error or message.info. The target classes are bootstrap classes and it works as expected.

```
<div
   className={classnames(`alert, ${styles.alertDiv}`, {
   "alert-danger": message.error,
   "alert-primary": message.info,
   })}
  >
```

Now, in place of alert-danger, I want to apply a style from a css file, $(styles.activeDiv) if message.error is true. In other words I want to replace alert-danger with $(styles.activeDiv). How do I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Next.js and in Bootstrap you are able to override the default CSS styling or write specific component level styling [Next.js Built-in CSS Support](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support). There are many ways to accomplish this, you could pass in a style object as an inline style attribute.  I think a simple way to do it is just to `useState` hooks.  This one toggles between two different CSS classes but you can alter to suit your needs:

In this example, the className changes when you click the div

[codesandbox example of Dynamic ClassName](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactnextjs-dynamic-classes-s9wo2)

```js
    import { useState } from "react";
    
    export default function IndexPage() {
      const [dynamicClassName, setDynamicClassName] = useState("info");
      
      const handleClassChange = () => {
        console.log("changing div class name");
        dynamicClassName === "info"
          ? setDynamicClassName("alert")
          : setDynamicClassName("info");
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <div className={dynamicClassName} onClick={handleClassChange}>
            This div has a dynamic CSS class based on click
          </div>
    
          <style jsx>
            {`
              .alert {
                color: red;
                border: 5px solid red;
              }
    
              .info {
                color: green;
                border: 5px solid green;
              }
            `}
          </style>
        </>
      );
    }
```

note: edited for a more specific working example

Comment: How do you optionally apply .alert-danger based on some condition, message.error==true, for instance?

Comment: @koque I updated with an example probably not your exact case but the concept is the same [codesandbox example of Dynamic ClassName toggle](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactnextjs-dynamic-classes-s9wo2)